# Simple Inequality, maximisation.

Tags: inequality

Maximise $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)$ when $a+b+c=1$.

I know the answer is just set $a=b=c=\frac{1}{3}$, and you could prove that by comparing two terms at a time: fix one term, and the two other terms are maximised when equal because of squares, so you need to set all 3 terms equal.

But is there any proper solution to this using real inequality techniques?

Comment: The most immediate method that comes to mind is that of [Lagrange multipliers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)

Comment: The maximum does not exist. For non-negative variables use AM-GM

Comment: &PrincessEev This is one of very many methods, which we can use here. LM here is one of bad ways for the solution

Answer (score 2):

The maximum value does not exist.

Try $a=b\rightarrow-\infty$.

For non-negative variables by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\prod_{cyc}(a+1)\leq\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+1)}{3}\right)^3=\frac{64}{27}.$$
The equality occurs for $a=b=c=\frac{1}{3},$ which says that we got a maximal value.